# Network connection lost when receiving or making a call using Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, calls, data-connection

Recently noticing that while making or receiving a call, the net connection on the Galaxy S2 is lost. Once the call is over, the connection is restored automatically. OS is android 2.3.6 (gingerbread).

can anyone please help if it is a handset problem or any setting that needs to be updated.

Comment: What cellular carrier are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely normal. GSM connections cannot maintain a data and voice connection at the same time. The S2 can, and will, however be able to make a voice call and still continue using a WiFi data connection.

This is true for MOST cellular providers in India, UNLESS they support the DTM protocol (highly doubtful).

Comment: GSM networks typically *do* support simultaneous voice/data, though. If they don't then the network is basically failing to meet the 3GPP specs (DTM was part of R4 of the spec, which was originally finalized around 2001). Not to say it's impossible, but if that's the case...ick.

Comment: @eldarerathis - speaking from personal experience as I have connections with two separate service providers (in India).